# Active Directory Domain Services Auditing

Tags: events, active-directory, auditing

I'll try to explain my goal as good as I can;

I want to trigger a script whenever there is a new computer added to a Organizational Unit.
To do this i need to activate the logging of this event under the local security policy/audit policy. I guess my question is, do I need to do this on all the domain controllers, or is it enough to do it one just one?
Also, is it possible to see the event from a member server with the Management Tools pack installed? As I don't want to put too much work on the Domain Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that gives 4 ways of tracking changes in Microsoft Active-Directory. You will find everything you need from configuring the eventlog to receiving notifications by way of different kind of polling.